# Overwriting an existing file in external storage using its URI [android]?

Tags: android, csv, uri, export-to-csv

I have an app that imports data from a .csv file by using its URI and a Scanner. It works like this:

```
private List<String[]> loadCSVfromURI(Uri file) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    Scanner csvFileScanner = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getContentResolver().openInputStream(file))));

    List<String[]> csvROW = new ArrayList<>();
    int tempRow = 0;
    while(csvFileScanner.hasNextLine()){
        String line = csvFileScanner.nextLine(); // Get single line from reader
        String[] splitLine = line.split(",");
        csvROW.add(tempRow, splitLine);
        tempRow++;
    }
    return csvROW;
}
```

My application has now edited the imported data (which was stored in a list of String arrays) and returned it to a single String. The data has been returned to a .CSV style format like so.

```
private String formatForCSV() {
    final String delimeter = "\n";
    StringBuilder formatCSVdata = new StringBuilder();
    String saveCSVrow;
    for(String[] thisRow: curCSV){
        saveCSVrow = String.join(",",thisRow);
        saveCSVrow = saveCSVrow + delimeter;
        formatCSVdata.append(saveCSVrow);
    }

    String saveCSV = formatCSVdata.toString();

    return saveCSV;
}
```

I now wish to save the String back to the original file, overwriting what was originally stored there but keeping the same location and file name. How can I perform the save/overwrite function using the URI from when the files data was first copied to my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I resolved this issue using the Content Resolver and by using openOutputStream.

```
OutputStream overWritter = null; //Outputstream to overwrite original content
    ContentResolver saveResolver = this.getContentResolver();
    try {
        overWritter = saveResolver.openOutputStream(originalURI);
        if (overWritter != null) {
            overWritter.write(myString.getBytes());
            overWritter.close();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Save Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Save Failure", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

This saves and overwrites the file at the original URI. I am open to better solutions. Maybe something more robust.

Comment: This is no longer working in API 29. E.g. If the second time `myString` is blank, the file is not saved.